# Javascript alert with variable after str.replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to strip some numbers from a text input, after splitting it to the first section. Then (for testing) use an alert to display the result.

The text input is meant to be an address so an example input is: **23 Waring Taylor Street, Wellington, New Zealand**

My code is:

```
function check() {
    var str = document.getElementById('autocomplete').val().split(',',1);
    res = str.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
    alert(res);
}
```

When I click the button to call funcion check() I get no alert box at all(im expecting one with **Waring Taylor Street)**, but if I remove the res =... line and alert str:

```
function check() {
    var str = document.getElementById('autocomplete').val().split(',',1);
    alert(str);
}
```

It works, and I get an alert with **23 Waring Taylor Street**. What is it about

```
res = str.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
```

that doesnt work?

any help much appreciated!

Comment: how does `document.getElementById('autocomplete').val()` work for you?? it should be `document.getElementById('autocomplete').value`

Comment: is it half jquery have javascript

Comment: 1) Can you give a sample input value?
2) Also expected output.

Comment: added examples @JeromeAnthony

Comment: @KeeghanMcGarry what do you mean "I get no output". Do you have an empty alert, or do you not have an alert. That's an important distinction.

Comment: @KevinJohnson I get no alert box

Comment: @KeeghanMcGarry, I think you could put a fiddle  to fully demonstrate your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified a little bit, but basically look at the zeroth spot in the array as the string (if you are limiting it to a length of one anyway), and use the replace function on that string -

```
<input id='autocomplete'/>
<button>Check</button>

$('button').on('click', function(){
    var str = $('#autocomplete').val().split(',',1)[0];
    var res = str.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
    alert(res);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/17bzhdea/

Comment: You, sir, have made my day!

Answer (score 0):

split() returns an array. You are trying the replace on the array. 
Try `str.join().replace()`

Comment: Doesn't it return one element of the array so actually this isn't a problem,

Comment: @eugensunic No, Jerome's right - it still returns an array, but the second parameter in the original post indicates that the array should only have a length of one. Alert still works with an array, but replace only works on a string.

Comment: tried to use res = str.join().replace(/[0-9]/g, '');  but still, nothing